# PHP Register Script - Forcing Specific Email Domain

Tags: php, email

I currently have a registration script on my website that requires the email to be from a specific domain.

So for this example, we will say that the user needs to signup using a @gmail.com email.

```
$gmail = 'gmail.com';
$emailCheck = strpos($_POST['email'],$gmail);
```

I then check to make sure the users form submitted email contains gmail.com before proceeding.

```
if($emailCheck === false) {
        $err[]='Only @gmail.com email addresses are currently accepted.';
}
```

I only then proceed to continue with the registeration using a check to see if any $err[] have occured.

```
if(!count($err)) {

        // INSERT IN DB, ETC. //
}
```

The issue I'm having is that if a user fills out user@yahoo.com the script provides and error. If the user provides user@gmail.com it works as it should. But if the user just inputs the first part of the email leaving out @gmail.com it also works, running the SQL query and inputing the values into the DB.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Given the code you posted, entering an email address that's not containing "gmail.com" will not execute the statements in the second `if` body, because $err will be set. Are you sure this is the code that's being executed?

Comment: Not really an answer, but I would suggest if(count($err) < 1) and also declaring $err = [] around your $gmail var.

Comment: Fixed it actually, you were right. I was also running a check to make sure it was a valid email address before paying it to if($emailCheck) that was causing the $emailcheck to be skipped not a full email was every submitted!

Answer (score 2):

```
$input=trim($_POST['email']);
if (preg_match("/^\S+@gmail\.com$/i", $input) {

// INSERT IN DB, ETC. //

}
else {
$err[]='Only valid <your_login>@gmail.com email addresses are currently accepted.';
}
```